# django-avatar difficulty overriding template

Tags: django, django-templates, http-status-code-403, django-csrf

I'm getting this error when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/avatar/change/` and click the button 'Upload New Image': 
`Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.`

So I went to `python27/Lib/site-packages/avatar/templates/avatar/change.html` and added 
`{% csrf_token %}` right after `<form ... POST...>`.

When I refresh the browser and view source I do not see the CSRF token, and the 403 message is still generated.

How do I modify the 'correct' django-avatar template?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there exist two `<form></form>` sections in the template.  Silly me.  I only added the `{% csrf_token %}` to the first form I found thinking that there was only one form defined under change.html.